# How I can set a routes for taxi only ? HERE Routing API

Tags: routes, here-api

I want to set routes where taxi allowed, using HERE Routing API. Does something API parameter exist for v.7 ?

https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/dev_guide/topics/request-constructing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The taxi transport mode is only available in the Routing API v8.

Comment: yes, thanks a lot, I saw it in v8 documentation (some beta mode), but didn't know about v7.